# Does java-library plugin fully cover java plugin functionality?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

According to [API and implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) doc the `java-library` plugin should be used to declare dependencies as `api`:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

Is `java-library` full replacement for `java` plugin? or there are cases when both of them should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java-library` is plugin is as it names implies: **a plugin for Java libraries**. If you are developing a library in Java, then it makes sense to use the `java-library` plugin.

If you are just developing a plain Java application, then simply use the `java` plugin as usual.

The `java-library` plugin applies the `java` plugin internally: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaLibraryPlugin.java#L38